# Is this possible to change the recurring payment amount after signing up?

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, recurring

I am Ritu from India.

I have a requirement that after signing up with a particular amount at PayPal Recurring Subscription, I need to change the amount from the next month. Is there any way for Standard PayPal Recurring Payment Subscription for changing the amount after the first month? If so, please let me know.

Thanks....

Comment: Possibly not an SO question but this is something I really want to know!

Comment: I suggest you contact your subscription provider about this. Stack Overflow is for Programming Q&A as defined in the [FAQ]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cancel the current subscription and create a new subscription. Paypal does not want to have people agreeing to a subscription at one amount and then the person or business who is receiving the money changing that amount without the permission of the subscriber. So you must go through the approval process again if you want to change the amount.

Comment: What about if sales taxes, e.g VAT changes? Do you really have to cancel and re-do?

Comment: What does PayPal care about VAT or taxes? They just transfer money for you, you need to take care of that on yourself. PayPal is not your bookkeeper.

Comment: @hakre: well in UK law for certain purchases you need to add VAT. In fact the VAT component should be quoted, and the fact that you can't quote it separately for subscription purchases (you can for one off purchases) means that PayPal essential operates in violation of the law. Anyway the point is that many services are subscription; the ability to adjust the VAT when it changes (and it frequently does) without the necessity of cancelling and requiring a customer to signup again I would have thought would be a necessary feature.

Comment: @Richard H: You mix the responsibility of yourself when doing a purchase to deal with VAT and the responsibility of the one who transfers the money to deal with VAT. VAT *might* apply to the service provided by Paypal and it *might* apply to the purchase operation as well. But Paypal's business is only to deal with their VAT application, not with yours. Next to that, Paypal might weight between flexibility for a customer and safeness for the other customer (the one who pays) - and offering you as the one who sales to adopt or not. But your business is your business, not theirs.

Comment: @Hakre: but don't you think having to cancel a subscription and get the customer to sign up again is a pain? For single payments paypal can add a sales tax (that you specify). Why not for recurring?

Comment: My guess is that the reason might be that one could change the VAT without the user having to reagree to those new conditions.

Comment: Back to the original problem, I am completely OK with the user authorising the change manually, IE I have a subscription model, many might start at £10 per month, but then upgrade to £20 per month, but if they do this, it is their choice (mostly) . I have one customer who accidentally subscribed at £20pm but now needs to switch down to £10pm.

Currently the only way I can see to do this is to cancel it manually myself and then get them to resubscribe - there MUST be a better less manual way!

Anyone want to help me do that?!